# узнать индекс массива на четное и не четное

Tags: php, массивы

есть массив `Array ( [0] => vadim [1] => 88 [2] => folder1 [3] => 100 )`
как получить такой массив `Array ([1] => 88 [3] => 100 )`
массив будет меняться то есть становится то больше то меньше, но всегда в таком порядке идёт

Comment: как соответствует заголовок вопроса и то, что нужно получить? в чем логика? куда делся вадим и почему?

Comment: я имею виду как поделить этот массив на четное и нечетное

Comment: ну если делится на 2 без остатка - значит четное. лично мне в школе так объясняли

Comment: так я тут и не могу понят как поделить сам идекс массива

Comment: `foreach ($arr as $key => $value) { ... `, где `$key` - ключ......... можно и обычный `for` со счетчиком

Answer (score 1):

Можно всё это дело в теле цикла написать, но мне нравятся функции. Примерно так

```
$arr = array('vadim', 88, 'folder1', 100);

$array = array_filter($arr, function($i) use(&$arr) {
    $bool = (key($arr) & 1);
    next($arr);
    return $bool;
});

echo '<pre>'; var_dump($array); echo '</pre>';
/*
 array(2) {
  [1]=>
  int(88)
  [3]=>
  int(100)
}
*/
```

Comment: так у меня массив другой

Comment: @Vadim разве не такой, как в первом посту? `array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "vadim"
  [1]=>
  int(88)
  [2]=>
  string(7) "folder1"
  [3]=>
  int(100)
}`

Comment: такой но вы написали array('vadim', 88, 'folder1', 100);

Comment: @Vadim если такой, то может быть просто скопируете код да посмотрите на его результат?

Comment: ваш код сработает но как мне свой код туда вставить

Comment: @Vadim сохраните в переменную $arr = ваш массив;

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62101/discussion-between--and-vadim).

Comment: сори я затупил, а можете мне в чате объяснить как работает

Comment: вы в курсе что с флагом `ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY ` код вашей функции фильтрации сведется к просто `return $i & 1` без костылей с `next` и `key` ?

Comment: @teran да, только этот флаг добавлен с версии 5.6.0, а я пишу на 5.4. Выше поднять не могу, железо старое.